# Difference between syscalls and raw_syscalls events?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

AFAIK different linux tracing tools gather information from /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events directory where different events are logged. Can anyone explain the difference between "syscalls" event and "raw_syscalls" event?

I want to know this difference in order to find out which event to trace if I want to log all system calls currently being invoked on my system. I know there are tools like strace and perf trace out there, but I want to create my own.